# Not able to reference foreign key other than primary in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models: Departments and DepartmentTypes. In DepartmentTypes i have a column "depth" serving as foreign key to departments (field: hirarchy_lvl). That said, i am trying to get the DepartmentType label to be displayed in a view but keep on failing...

Here's what i have:

Department.php:

```
public function departmentType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DepartmentType::class, 'depth', 'hirarchy_lvl');
    }
```

DepartmentType.php

```
public function department()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Department::class, 'hirarchy_lvl', 'depth');
    }
```

db schema create:

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('department_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->bigInteger('depth')->unsigned()->unique();
        $table->string('hirarchy_lvl_name');
    });

    DB::table('department_types')->insert(array('created_at' => now(), 'depth' => '10', 'hirarchy_lvl_name' => 'company'));
    DB::table('department_types')->insert(array('created_at' => now(), 'depth' => '20', 'hirarchy_lvl_name' => 'department'));
    DB::table('department_types')->insert(array('created_at' => now(), 'depth' => '30', 'hirarchy_lvl_name' => 'team'));
    DB::table('department_types')->insert(array('created_at' => now(), 'depth' => '40', 'hirarchy_lvl_name' => 'individual'));



    Schema::table('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('hirarchy_lvl')->references('depth')->on('department_types')->onDelete('NO ACTION')->change();    //shall reference other objective
    });

}
```

In the controller:

```
    public function listDepartmentsByHirarchy($hirLvl = 0){
    if($hirLvl){
        $departments = Department::where('hirarchy_lvl', $hirLvl)->get();           
    }
    else 
    {
        $departments = Department::get();                       
    }
    $department_types = DepartmentType::get();
    return view('configcenter/listDepartments', compact('departments', 'department_types'));
}
```

Testing in the view:

```
<td>
    {{$department}}
</td>
```

gives me:

```
{"id":2,"created_at":"2019-12-18 13:04:11","updated_at":null,"description":"dep1","parent_dep":{"id":1,"created_at":"2019-12-18 13:04:11","updated_at":null,"description":"company","parent_dep":1,"hirarchy_lvl":10},"hirarchy_lvl":20}
```

Leading me to the conclusion that the foreign key does not get resolved properly (as it's just the value rather than the object i would need over here).

Now, after studying the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)  and several posts, i cannot help myself but ask the noobish question: how do i reference the foreign key properly so i can work on the object in the view?

appreciate any hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Department::departmentType()` relationship is incorrect, I believe. The fields should be switched.

When defining the `belongsTo` side of the relationship, the second parameter is the field on the defining model (`departments.hirarchy_lvl`) and the third parameter is the field on the related model (`department_types.depth`).

When defining the `hasOne/hasMany` side of the relationship, it is the opposite. The second parameter is the field on the related model, and the third parameter is the field on the defining model.

Department.php:

```
public function departmentType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(DepartmentType::class, 'hirarchy_lvl', 'depth');
}
```

DepartmentType.php

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Department::class, 'hirarchy_lvl', 'depth');
}
```